# Regular Expression \w is not working

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core

I am working an an asp.net core app.

I have validation in place..

I am trying to prohibit the user from entering only spaces. So I use this:

```
    [Display(Name = "Reason for Cancellation")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"\w", ErrorMessage = CancellationValidationErrorMessage)]
    [StringLength(245)] // 245 characters to allow for History Type prefix to be added
    public string CancelJustificationComments { get; set; }
```

And whilst the error pops up stating that i must supply an entry I also get the error on any other input as well.

What is wrong?

Comment: Try pattern: `[^ ]`.

Comment: have you tries `@"\w+"` for more than one character

Comment: @Tushortz thanks. just tried that ad it did not work :(

Comment: @MichałTurczyn nor that :(

Comment: Try adding anchors ie @"^\w+$"

Comment: @JGNI i am afraid not...

Comment: Well, it looks like you have error somewhere else. Did you try deleting the attribute and see what is happening then?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn yes, works fine...

Comment: Does `@"\W"` work?

Comment: Do you want to block spaces or accept only spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex validator requires that the whole text matches the regex. So this \w only matches a single character entry.

Solution: add some wildcards around it: `.*\w.*`

Comment: thanks. so simple after all!  I feel like a right idiot:)