# Regular Expression .*\w.* is not working when user adds a line feed

Tags: c#, regex

this is related to my previous question: [Regular Expression \w is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785726/regular-expression-w-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment90529935_51785726)

the input field is a TextArea and I start off by pressing enter to create a line feed. I then add some text and press my button.

The entry is rejected as not a valid entry.

I need to able to accept anything providing it has at least 1 word which it does using the expression

```
[RegularExpression(@".*\w.*", ErrorMessage = CancellationValidationErrorMessage)]
```

but not if the User has entered a line feed before hand. Though I suspect this may be for any special character like [tab] etc..

Comment: Dot never matches newline, unless you enable single-line mode.

Comment: @KennethK. Thanks for commenting.  But i am using the TextArea input field so it is multi-line by default?

Comment: @KennethK. Not sure if I replied intelligently there or not lol.  Is there a solution?

Comment: What input you are using is irrelevant. This is a regex problem. You need to understand what the tokens in your regex represent.

Comment: @KennethK.yes, I know that. that is why I have posted this question.

Comment: @KennethK. if I  was not using attributes I could strip out the new lines etc. But I am having to use attributes

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Comment: @KennethK. and arrogant I may add. Now downvote as i predict u will and go away :)

Answer (score 0):

From your previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785726/regular-expression-w-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment90529935_51785726)..

> "I am trying to prohibit the user from entering only spaces."

It's simpler if you use `[Required(ErrorMessage = CancellationValidationErrorMessage)]` that will validate if it's empty or not.

Based in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) info:

> "...data field cannot be empty..."

Comment: Thanks, glad to see some one is trying to help :) Unfortunately this does not work because the User can just type in a load of spaces.I need at least a single word. But thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson something is wrong because they say [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) this _"The RequiredAttribute attribute specifies that when a field on a form is validated, the field must contain a value. A validation exception is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), **or contains only white-space characters**."_

Comment: You are correct  But it does not work as I described. Do not know why.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Note the note below that transcription.. _"If the MVC data model or entity partial class contains a field that is annotated with the RequiredAttribute attribute, but the page does not contain the property, an error is not raised. Validation occurs only for fields that are submitted to the server."_.. Could this be your scenario?

Comment: I am afraid not.  This is the primary field I am returning to the server.  But thanks for thinking outside the box for me

Comment: Ok, try this expression then `[^\s]`.

"\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])", so if your text only contains white spaces ([\r\n\t\f\v ]) it won't get any match and the exception will be thrown.

Comment: Will be back 10 mins to try ta